# Is there a limit on number of recipients that blat can send email to

Tags: java, blat

I have a java application that does generates a report and then calls blat utility to send out the report as email attachment.

The email info such as from, to, subject, message, etc are written in an .ini file. 
So the java application first generates a report, extracts info from .ini file and then calls blat with  the give info to send out an email.

Everything seems, in terms of generating report, sending an email and so on,is working perfectly fine until I add more than 3 recipients to the email list.

Basically when I have 3 recipients in the list I can see the report being generated and also being dumped on command line (for verification purposes), and a quick open & close of command line utility to send out email through blat.

But when I add the 4th recipient in the list, I can see the report being generated and also being dumped on command line but from here on the program seems to be sitting there (seems like its waiting for blat)... but never executes blat\send out email.

I have tried adding all 4 recipients to '-to' flag and also to split recipients among '-to' and '-cc' flag. But the outcome stays same.

Any help, or thoughts are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your email server is doing something to it.  Can you send the same attachment with the same id from your desk?  also, how big is the report?  some servers multiply the attachment size by the number of mailboxes involved (including the 'To' address) to come up with the message size limit.